# Regex pspad to replace item in line based on inclusion of other pattern

Tags: regex, pspad

I need to match an item in a line that, upon finding this, will replace another item in the line.  Ex:

Find all lines containing: `code="ap"`
Replace: `quant="*****"` with `quant="0"`

Note that the quant field I will need to replace could have multiple variables between the quotes.

I tried from another thread:
Need: replace "BBB" with "CCC" but only in lines that contain the word "AAA"

Search: `((?=.*?AAA)[^\r\n]*)(BBB)`

Replace: `$1CCC`

However, I'm not sure if it will work with the quotes included in my find or how to enter the variable data in the initial quant replace.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will do the following:

- validate the line contains `code="ap"`, if the line does not contain this string then no replacements will be made on the line
- find the first `quantity="somevalue"` string and replace with `quantity="0"`
- allow `quantity`'s value to be any value, to include spaces and other special characters
- avoid difficult edge cases
- allow the `code` and `quantity` key names to appear in any order on the line
- allow the values to be surrounded by single or double quotes or no quotes

## The Regular Expression

For this regex I used the case insenstive and multiline flags

```
^(?=(?:[^=\r\n]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s]*)*?code=(['"]?)ap\1)((?:[^=\r\n]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s]*)*?quantity=)(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s\n\r]*)(.*?)$
```

Replace with:

```
$2"0"$3
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note: to see the image better right click and select open in new window

## Examples

**Source Text**

Note the difficult edge case in the last several lines.

```
code="ap" quantity="SomeValue" other="values"
code="Not ap" quantity="SomeValue"
code="ap" quantity="SomeValue"
quantity="AlsoSomeValue2" code="ap" 
code="ap" other=' quantity="Save this value" ' quantity="SomeValue"
code="Not ap" quantity="SomeValue" other=' Code="ap" '
```

**After Replace**

```
code="ap" quantity="0" other="values"
code="Not ap" quantity="SomeValue"
code="ap" quantity="0"
quantity="0" code="ap" 
code="ap" other=' quantity="Save this value" ' quantity="0"
code="Not ap" quantity="SomeValue" other=' Code="ap" '
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^=\r\n]                 any character except: '=', '\r'
                               (carriage return), '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s]*                   any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    code=                    'code='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ap                       'ap'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^=\r\n]                 any character except: '=', '\r'
                               (carriage return), '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s]*                   any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    quantity=                'quantity='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s\n\r]*               any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), '\n' (newline),
                             '\r' (carriage return) (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
```